# json_query in Ansible filtering output from nvme command returns nothing?

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, jmespath

I'm having a hell of a time trying to use `json_query` to filter the JSON output of some external command (`nvme list -o json`).

The `nvme` output is captured in Ansible with this:

```yaml
- name: Run nvme command
  command:
    cmd: nvme list -o json
  register: nvme_output
  become: yes
```

Contains:

```yaml
- name: nvme_ouput stdout
  debug:
    var: nvme_output.stdout
```

```
TASK [general : nvme_ouput stdout] *********************************************
ok: [dev-0600099bfee3c0f60.internal] => {
    "nvme_output.stdout": {
        "Devices": [
            {
                "DevicePath": "/dev/nvme0n1",
                "Firmware": "1.0",
                "Index": 0,
                "MaximumLBA": 33554432,
                "ModelNumber": "Amazon Elastic Block Store",
                "PhysicalSize": 17179869184,
                "ProductName": "Non-Volatile memory controller: Vendor 0x1d0f Device 0x8061",
                "SectorSize": 512,
                "SerialNumber": "vol0e6af89fd1991cwtf",
                "UsedBytes": 0
            },
            {
                "DevicePath": "/dev/nvme1n1",
                "Firmware": "1.0",
                "Index": 1,
                "MaximumLBA": 104857600,
                "ModelNumber": "Amazon Elastic Block Store",
                "PhysicalSize": 53687091200,
                "ProductName": "Non-Volatile memory controller: Vendor 0x1d0f Device 0x8061",
                "SectorSize": 512,
                "SerialNumber": "vol0885625da4a60awtf",
                "UsedBytes": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I now need all the `DevicePath`s. Using the online tester on eg. https://jmespath.org/, I came up with this rather simple query: `Devices[*].DevicePath`

Trying to use it in Ansible:

```yaml
- name: nvme_ouput json_query var
  debug:
    msg: "{{ nvme_output.stdout | json_query(jq) }}"
  vars:
    jq: >-
      Devices[*].DevicePath
```

But…

```
TASK [general : nvme_ouput json_query var] *********************
ok: [dev-0600099bfee3c0f60.internal] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

**Why is the output of `json_query()` empty?**

---

I'm running this on AWS EC2 on a Debian 10 system, if it matters, with:

```
ansible-playbook 2.7.7
  config file = /home/alex/sysops-ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/alex/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/cb8a798f8913f401b374474fc4121dea